# One Transaction across 3 schemas?

Tags: java, oracle, transactions, entity, entitymanager

I have created a `Java` Application that deletes data from my `Oracle` database.

The application deletes rows across 3 schemas:

```
public class ServiceThree {     

    public void loopThroughDeletesAtProjectLevel(List<EntityToDelete> entityList) {

            for (int i = 0; i < entityList.size(); i++) {

                serviceOne.deleteFromSchemaOne(\);
                serviceTwo.deleteFromSchemaTwo(entityList.get(i));
                deleteFromSchemaThree(entityList.get(i));
            }   
        }

    }
```

Inside each of these delete methods is when I include my transactions, e.g:

```
public void deleteFromSchemaOne(){

repositoryOne.startTransaction();

//logic to carry out deletions 
repositoryOne.deleteAllRelevantData(EntityToDelete);

repositoryOne.commitTransaction();
}
```

How can I ensure that all the data from the Three schemas is deleted in the **ONE** `transaction`, i.e if there is an error in any of the three schemas then it will `rollback`?

Comment: I have never done this but I vaguely recall it should be possible using [XA transations](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077714/java-web-development/xa-transactions-using-spring.html).

Comment: Don't start transaction inside each of your procedures. Instead, start the transaction before calling the first procedure and commit it after the last procedure. Best of luck.

Comment: You're going to need a heavyweight, probably external transaction manager. They're available, but they're not simple to set up.

Comment: @chrylis can you please expand on what you mean by this?